# AngularJS : service not updating

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, sails.js, angular-services

I'm new to Angular, and this is stumping me.

I'm authenticating using oAuth in a popup, and I've gotten as far as returning the user and closing the popup. I'm having difficulty getting the controller to update when `isLoggedIn` is set. I followed the steps at http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/ but I can't get it to work. I know the value is being set, because manually refreshing the user works. I'd like to be able to avoid using `$scope.$watch` in all of my controllers if at all possible.

**currentUser.coffee Service**

```
app.service 'currentUser',
  ['$sails', '$window',
  ( $sails,   $window ) ->

    @isLoggedIn = false

    @loginWithFacebook = ->

      # open popup
      left  = screen.width / 2 - 200
      top   = screen.height / 2 - 250
      popup = $window.open('/auth/facebook', '', "top=#{top}, left=#{left}, width=400, height=500")

      # close popup and set currentUser
      $window.completeLogin = (user) =>
        @isLoggedIn = true
        popup.close()

    return
]
```

**navCtrl.coffee**

```
app.controller 'navCtrl',
  ['$scope', 'currentUser'
  ( $scope,   currentUser) ->

    $scope.user = currentUser
    $scope.refreshUser = ->
      $scope.user = currentUser
]
```

**nav.jade**

```
.text-center(ng-hide='user.isLoggedIn')
  h4: strong WhatWhenWhere
  h6.subheader: strong Sign in to get the whole shebang

  br

  form
    input(type='text', placeholder='Email')
    input(type='Password', placeholder='Password')
    input.button.tiny(type='submit', value='LOG IN')

  small: em &mdash; or &mdash;

  br

  a.facebook.button.tiny(ng-click='user.loginWithFacebook()'): strong Log in with Facebook

  hr

  a Create an account

{{ user }}

a(ng-click="refreshUser()") refreshUser
```

**edit:** I've noticed that if I click "Log in with Facebook" a second time, the UI updates. No idea as to why yet.

**edit 2:** Well, I figured I'd give in for the time being and reload the page, so I added `$route.reload()` to the `$window.completeLogin` function, and it doesn't reload the page,
but it causes the controller to update. So, problem is solved, but I'd really like to understand what's actually happening here, and make it work without that addition if possible.

Comment: I'm not a coffeescript expert but it doesn't look like you return anything from the service definition

Comment: @ExplosionPills Coffeescript uses ruby-style implicit returns, thus the empty return at the end of the currentUser service